# Error C2079 'std::pair<Dummy<int>,Dummy<int>>::first' uses undefined class 'Dummy<int>'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

The following code snippet compiles just fine with GCC 9.1 and Clang 6.0 under C++11/14/17 standards, but refuses to compile with Visual Studio 2019.  I can change the return of `getDummies()` to `auto` and VS will compile with C++14/17 standards, but this breaks C++11 compatibility on all compilers, which I need to keep.

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
class Dummy
{
public:
    //static auto getDummies() // Works but breaks C++11 compatibility
    static std::pair<Dummy<int>, Dummy<int>> getDummies()
    {
        return std::make_pair(Dummy<int>{}, Dummy<int>{});
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto dummies = Dummy<int>::getDummies(); // Error C2079

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `Dummy` is not fully defined at the point that the `getDummies()` function is defined, inside the class.

You can *declare* the function in the class then define it outside the class, like:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class Dummy
{
public:
    static std::pair<Dummy<int>, Dummy<int>> getDummies();
};

template<typename T>
std::pair<Dummy<int>, Dummy<int>> Dummy<T>::getDummies()
{
    return std::make_pair(Dummy<int>{}, Dummy<int>{});
}
```

Comment: It doesn't matter that it's not fully defined, the OP's definition is still standard

Comment: I find it annoying that this is needed in Visual Studio but it does work.  Thanks!